# Node.js event handling order

Tags: events, node.js

Given some [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter) instance in [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/), is it absolutely guaranteed that all events will be handled in the same order as they appear in the code?

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var inherits = require('util').inherits;

var Emitter = function () {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
    var that = this;
    this.test = function () {            
        that.emit('eventA');
        that.emit('eventB');
    }
};
inherits(Emitter, EventEmitter);

var emitter = new Emitter();

emitter.on('eventA', function () {
    doTaskA();
});

emitter.on('eventB', function () {
    doTaskB();
});

emitter.test();
```

Can there appear a situation where `doTaskB()` will start before `doTaskA()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, all events will be handled in the same order as they appear in the code. Event is fired immediately after the emit call. You can see it in EventEmmiter.emit [source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/events.js). But binding your application logic to the order of events does not the best way.

Comment: not really a good way to program. The Events are fired in the order specified, yes, but that doesn't necessarily mean taskA will finish before taskB, or that taskA is finished when taskB is fired. To prevent that from happening, use a flow control lib such as [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or one of [these](http://dailyjs.com/2012/02/20/new-flow-control-libraries/). I'm in the process of switching from async to invoke..

Comment: @japrescott I would also suggest putting [asyncblock](https://github.com/scriby/asyncblock) on the list.

Comment: The [unit tests](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/test/simple/test-event-emitter-modify-in-emit.js#L56) define that they should be in that order too, so that means that implementation changes won't alter that.